# Android Studio: how to change location of android/gradle folders

Tags: android-studio, gradle, directory, onedrive

I've just installed Android Studio for the first time, and some of the folders went straight to my OneDrive folder: ".android", ".AndroidStudio1.2" and ".gradle."

Apparently, they get automatically saved in the parent folder of your "Desktop" folder (and this is where I keep mine). A bit wierd if you ask me.

Because of that OneDrive has 1-2 GB of data to upload after every time I use the studio.

Any solution to that weird problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Such, a shame no one seems to know that. It's a massive pain in the bum.